# how to put laravel echo function in javascript

Tags: javascript, laravel

How to use echo in strings in javascript datatable

```
className:'text-center', 
data:'stage', 
name:'stage',
render: function(data)
{
    return '<td class="text-center">{{trans('stage.'' + data.stage + ')}}</td>';
}
```

error: syntax error, unexpected ''+ data.stage +'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ')'

I have tried escaping using backlash it still doesnt look right.

```
<td class="text-center">{{trans('stage.'.$sub->stage)}}</td> 
//this is what i want to display if i were to use laravel blade
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blade is rendered before you hit the page. So you cannot do what you're trying to, like this. I would recommend using xDebug to see how this works more consistently

If you want to include a translated variant of text in the variable `stage`, you either need to fetch some HTML and pass it back rendered, via an `ajax` request for example

**OR**

You can write/use a javaScript helper which will translate text for you.

**OR (best)**

You can write an accessor/getter on `stage` which will translate it before it's received by your DataTable

This would mean writing the following on the `Model` where the attribute `stage` comes from. Please note, prefixed Method name with 'get' and 'Attribute' as the suffix.

```
    public function getStageAttribute()
    {
        return trans($this->stage);
    }
```

For more information please see https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Comment: thanks, i think the later would be the best method to do it